# onRemoteMediaPlayerMetadataUpdated is not called when media information is updated

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I'm working on a Chromecast Receiver application and trying to introduce a queueing logic now. It was decided to keep a queueing logic on the receiver side so that when the current track finishes, the next one is chosen on a receiver side. All sender apps are supposed to be notified about this change.

Unfortunately, `onRemoteMediaPlayerMetadataUpdated` callback is not called on a sender side when a receiver sends media information update.

Our approach was inspired by `CastVideosPlaylist` app we found on [github](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideosPlaylist-chrome/blob/master/player_playlist_receiver.html#L70-L99). The reason we don't wait for `loadedmetadata` is because sender is not interested in such meta information as `duration`.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

The code we use looks pretty much like this.

```js
var mediaElement = new Audio();
var mediaManager = new cast.receiver.MediaManager(mediaElement);

mediaManager.onEnded = (function(){

  var origFn = mediaManager.onEnded;

  return function(event) {
    // passing the control to Chromecast Media Manager
    origFn.call(mediaManager, event);

    var nextTrack = getNextTrack();

    if (nextTrack) {
      var mediaInfo = new cast.receiver.media.MediaInformation();

      mediaInfo.duration = nextTrack.duration;
      mediaInfo.contentId = nextTrack.contentId;
      mediaInfo.streamType = 'BUFFERED';
      mediaInfo.contentType = 'audio/mpeg';

      // broadcasting information about next track to all senders
      mediaManager.setMediaInformation(mediaInfo);

      // rendering a new player
      renderTrackView(nextTrack);
    }
  }

}());

mediaManager.setMediaInformation = (function() {
  var origFn = mediaManager.setMediaInformation.bind(mediaManager);

  // redefining `MediaManager#setMediaInformation` so that a play queue is sent back to senders
  // whenever a media information is updated
  return function(mediaInformation, opt_broadcast, opt_broadcastStatusCustomData) {
    mediaInformation.customData = {
      play_queue: playQueue.getTracks()
    };
    origFn(mediaInformation, opt_broadcast, opt_broadcastStatusCustomData);
  }
}());
```

Comment: Why don't you set the customData directly for the next track, instead of overriding the setMediaInformation function?

Comment: Well, initially I used `mediaManager.customizedStatusCallback` in order to modify media status object so that it includes the current play queue info, but it wasn't very useful since the console output was overloaded with a huge object we were sending everytime the communication betweeb receiver and sender took place.

Comment: Eventually, I came up with an idea of overriding `MediaManager#setMediaInformation` because that ensures that play queue info is sent back to sender whenever media information is updated -- that's kind of a requirement from sender side

Comment: I meant why don't you set the customdata when you set the other MediaInfo fields for the next track? You should not have to override any other functions other than onEnded. Not sure why you would see anything in the logs unless you have debugging enabled.

Comment: Well, I can remove customData for now. What is the most important in this question is how to notify a sender about next track so that `onRemoteMediaPlayerMetadataUpdated ` is executed.

Comment: mediaManager.broadcastStatus(true);